# Problem with creating tables in sql python file

Tags: python, mysql, django

i got an Error when i'm trying to crate table and my sql server

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE countries (name VARCHAR(300), population size INTEGER(10), \
capital city VARCHAR(300))")
mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
for tb in mycursor:
    print(tb)
```

can anyone knows what is the problem with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try [population size] INTEGER(10), 
[capital city] VARCHAR(300))")